# ASP.NET Core 6.0 and Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm writing an API using .NET 6.0. I need to use third party assembly which refers to Windows.Form (.NET Framework 4.72).

It is throwing an exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0...'

Is there any chance to use it or do I have to lower expectations?
If not 6.0 then which version would?

---

EDIT:

Thanks to Jeremy Lakeman this:

> <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />

helped for Windows.Forms problem, but I failed anyway.

Now there is missing reference for System.Web.Services and this is bigger issue, I think.

Comment: .net 6.0 is `.net core` under the hood, that probably won't work with your .net FRAMEWORK 4.72 assembly. Simply create your app using .net framework 4.72.

Comment: Reading between the lines; (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop" />` ?

Comment: Generally, windows forms components aren't going to be a good fit for an ASP.NET app anyway. What does this third-party assembly do?

Comment: This third party assembly is in fact big fat app with many dll. I need to use only few of them to make an Rest API for some data from that app. ASP.NET api is easy to make so it is temptng to give it a shot. I'd like to use as new version as I can. So starting form .net 6.0. I know that is not designed this way but it doesn't mean it won't work. Maybe there is a way.